# Material ui stlyes are changing from the default style in my project

Tags: css, material-ui

I am using Material ui in my project when i copy component from material ui and paste it ,fontColor ,fontWeight changed ,etc from default style making it invisible  to see when i use same components in other project file it work properly and i dont have any overridden default styles .

I tried everything ,searching on internet but i don get solution to my problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sirji, Edit your question and sample code share kro apne component da? Ya fir koi codesandbox share kro if possible.